# Can inputs be at the source/drain of MOSFETs for digital logic circuits?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates

There is a question in my University exam requiring us to design a logic circuit for the following logic using the smallest number of transistors:

[image]

I was trying to optimise at the gate level by using NAND/NOR gates only as I know they are the gates that have reduction functions with the minimum number of transistors (four).

However, the answer of the question was wired to me where they have inputs at the MOSFET sources, as shown below.

[image]

I was wondering if such configurations are really allowed and used in practice in modern integrated circuits as I have never seen them anywhere before.

For modern IC design, do logic synthesisers optimise at the gate level (i.e. logic gates are the smallest units) or at the transistor level by realising arbitrary logic functions such as (ab + c) like shown below?

[image]

Comment: Where is \$V_{DD}\$ in your first diagram? CG circuits at the input in CMOS ICs are, AFAIK, not used as their input impedance is quite low. Maybe after a buffer they can be used.

Comment: @HarryH There seems to be no $V_DD$; this was the exact answer given. Also what does CG stand for? Thanks.

Comment: Ok. 'CG' stands for 'common gate'. Here the source terminal is the input and the gate is then connected to ground. Here the gate is also an input, but the source terminal doesn't know that and just sees a rather low impedance.

Answer (score 2):

It was very common in TTL era.
However, the input impedance is usually lower compared to gate controlling.

[image]

Source: https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:TTL_NAND_003.svg

Answer (score 0):

It's unconventional and you'll probably have issues with the logical threshold and current bias for the family you are targeting. However if it works reliably go for it.

As for manufacturing: design is done using macro cell defined by you silicon process (usually). So you generally work at the gate or pseudo-gate level. You have a NAND block, a transmission gate block and so on, the synthesis tool uses them.